# wp-pagenavi only showing first page

Tags: plugin-wp-pagenavi

I'm trying to get pagination to work, I get the nav tools to show, but when i click to move to the next page it loads the first page every time. Here's the code:

```
<?php $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'page',
                    'orderby' => 'title',
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'posts_per_page' => 5,
                    'paged' => get_query_var('page'),
                    'post_parent' => $parent
                ); ?>
          <?php query_posts($args); ?>

          <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
              <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                  //get the desired custom field values 
              <?php endwhile; ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </div>

        <!-- navigation goes here -->
        <div class="naviButs">
            <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
        </div>
```

Please if anyone can assist? Or maybe knows workaround?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace 'page' with 'paged':

```
'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
```